# Increasing speead of O(n^2) and O(n^3) in Matlab when n ~ 100K

Tags: matlab, kinect, point-clouds

I want to create a graph from 3D points clouds captured by Microsoft Kinect in Matlab. It is about only 100K Points. I wrote very simple program which is only a nested for i.e. O(n^2) as follow:

```
load('Points_Sample1.mat')
Points=single(Points);
x=Points(1,:);
y=Points(2,:);
z=Points(3,:);

tic
for i=1:n
    xi=x(i);
    yi=y(i);
    zi=z(i);
   for j=1:n
        xj=x(j);
        yj=y(j);
        zj=z(j);
   end
end
toc
```

the result is:

```
Elapsed time is 122.398886 seconds.
```

In other word a simple for loop take 122 seconds! I run it with:

> Matlab 2016a
>
> Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit
>
> Intel Core i7-3820 @ 3.6 GHz with 16 GB RAM

In this speed, I cannot even think about O(n^3)

I want to run whole program less than 1s. before testing above program I expected to run less than 0.1 Second.

**Edit 1:**

1) two users comment about XY! I want to create weighted graph (data structure) from the points and use this graph to find objects (size, position, direction).

2) one user comments on vectorize calculations, its very good. however, the pc has only 16GB RAM. vectorize calculations with n~100K needs 128GB!

3) other user comments on O(n^2) notation and running time. Any peogram in O(n^3) should take more time than only just loop. I want to say that when nly simple loop take 122 second, if I add more line, it will take more than 122 second. I need to decreas it to 0.1 second (if not possible at most 1 second)

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Right now you only overwrite the same three variables in each iteration.

Comment: If you cannot avoid big loops and speed matters for you, maybe Matlab is not the best programming language you could choose. In most of the cases you could partially or fully vectorize your calculations which dramatically increases the speed. If you don't know how to vectorize calculations, you could [check this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) or edit your question and share some of the operations you are doing in the loop.

Comment: Side note: `O` notation does not tell you how fast an algorithm goes, but how it scales with input. You can make an algorithm that is `O(n)` and takes milenia to compute, and algorithms that are `O(n^2)` and work in milliseconds. The `O` notation is usefull to know once you ran the algorithm with 1 array size, how much will it take in comparison with an array of a different size.

Comment: That said, I'd rephrase the question, as you are just assuming that 2 loops-> `O(n^2)` -> every `O(n^2)` will take the same time, and that is, just plainly wrong. Do put the code you want to work with, and well help optimize

Comment: Adding to the words of my esteemed colleagues, please read about (and be aware of) the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) and make sure you're not stepping on that rake...

Comment: Unless you tell us what you're actually trying to do, we can't help you. As it stands, this is question is simply "why do big loops take a long time?" and there is no constructive answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to compare all N points against all N-1 other points?  Or is it sufficient to process pairs of points which are relatively near to each other?  Most physical phenomena decrease rapidly as separation increases, so it is possible you can either neglect the effect of distant points, or else consider the combined effect of a large number of distant points as if they were all located at a single direction and distance.

Take a look at data structures such as octtrees that allow efficiently finding nearby points, while grouping far points into clusters.